# How to forecast out-of-sample value in sktime SquaringResiduals?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arch, sktime

I am trying to forecast out-of-sample value using sktime SquaringResiduals.
Here is the code which working well for in-sample prediction.

```
from sktime.forecasting.arch import StatsForecastGARCH
from sktime.forecasting.squaring_residuals import SquaringResiduals
def hybridModel(p,q,model):
    out_sample_date = FH(np.arange(12), is_relative=True)
    in_sample_date = FH(df.index, is_relative=False)
    var_fc = StatsForecastGARCH(p=p,q=q)  
    sqr = SquaringResiduals(forecaster=model, residual_forecaster=var_fc,initial_window=int(len(df))) 
    sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=in_sample_date)  
    # y_pred2 = sqr.predict(out_sample_date) #out sample prediction 
    y_pred = sqr.predict(in_sample_date) #in sample prediction
    fig,ax=plot_series(df, y_pred, labels=["passenger", "y_pred"])
    return sqr,fig,y_pred,error_matrix(df,y_pred)
sqr,fig1,y_pred1,matrix1= hybridModel(1,1,forecaster)
```

Now I try to forecast out-sample.
`y_pred2 = sqr.predict(out_sample_date) #out sample prediction`

```
> ValueError: A different forecasting horizon `fh` has been provided
> from the one seen already in `fit`, in this instance of
> SquaringResiduals. If you want to change the forecasting horizon,
> please re-fit the forecaster. This is because the fitting of the
> forecaster SquaringResiduals depends on `fh`.
```

So I change:`sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=in_sample_date)`  to `sqr = sqr.fit(df)`

```
> ValueError: The forecasting horizon `fh` must be passed to `fit` of
> SquaringResiduals, but none was found. This is because fitting of the
> forecaster SquaringResiduals depends on `fh`.
```

Then I change: `sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=in_sample_date)`  to `sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=out_sample_date)`

```
> ValueError: The `window_length` and the forecasting horizon are
> incompatible with the length of `y`. Found `window_length`=84,
> `max(fh)`=11, but len(y)=84. It is required that the window length
> plus maximum forecast horizon is smaller than the length of the time
> series `y` itself.
```

Then I checked predict function for other model, and predict() function working well for both in-sample and out-sample prediction for non-hybrid model:

```
from sktime.forecasting.tbats import TBATS
from sktime.forecasting.base import ForecastingHorizon as FH
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mlflow
from sktime.utils import mlflow_sktime as mf
from sktime.utils.plotting import plot_series
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
out_sample_date = FH(np.arange(12), is_relative=True)
in_sample_date = FH(df.index, is_relative=False)
forecaster = TBATS(  
    use_box_cox=True,
    use_trend=True,
    use_damped_trend=True,
    sp=12,
    use_arma_errors=True,
    n_jobs=1)
forecaster.fit(df)  
y_pred = forecaster.predict(in_sample_date)  
y_pred2 = forecaster.predict(out_sample_date)
fig,ax = plot_series(df,y_pred,y_pred2,labels=['passenger','prediction','out_sample_pred'])
```

[image]

Why out-sample / in-sample prediction function does not work together for SquaringResiduals and how can we predict out-sample / in-sample value?

```
sqr = SquaringResiduals(forecaster=model, residual_forecaster=var_fc,initial_window=int(len(df))) 
sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=in_sample_date)  
y_pred2 = sqr.predict(out_sample_date) #out sample prediction
```

Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: what is `error_matrix`?

Comment: error_matrix is a function that returns error and accuracy which works well, only in-sample / out-sample prediction does not work together for the squaringResiduals model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.sktime.net/en/stable/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.squaring_residuals.SquaringResiduals.html) explains that the forecaster is trained on `y(t_1),...y(t_i)` where `i = initial_window, ... N-steps_ahead`, and that this is used to calculate the residual `r(t_i+steps_ahead) := y(t_i+steps_ahead) - ŷ(t_i+steps_ahead)` for each value of i.

The `initial_window` must be less than or equal to `N-steps_ahead` to make any forecasts for a positive number of `steps_ahead`. I believe the reason for this is if we consider `initial_window = N-s` where s is greater than or equal to 0, and `steps_ahead=a`, then in the first iteration of the loop over i, we get:

```
r(t_i+steps_ahead) := y(t_i+steps_ahead) - ŷ(t_i+steps_ahead)
r(t_(N-s+a)) := y(t_(N-s+a)) - ŷ(t_(N-s+a))
```

Notice that `y(t_(N-s+a))` is not known unless `N-s+a <= N`, or equivalently `a < s` because we don't know the true value of future timestamps.

This means when you use SquaringResiduals, the maximum possible initial window you can supply is `max_initial_window = len(df)-max(out_sample_date)`. Notice that we are using max(out_sample_date) and not len(out_sample_date) because `np.arange(12)` only asks for forecasts of `steps_ahead = 0, ... 11` or a maximum forecast horizon of 11.

Below is a fully reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sktime.forecasting.arch import StatsForecastGARCH
from sktime.forecasting.squaring_residuals import SquaringResiduals

from sktime.forecasting.tbats import TBATS
from sktime.forecasting.base import ForecastingHorizon as FH
import warnings
import mlflow
from sktime.utils import mlflow_sktime as mf
from sktime.utils.plotting import plot_series
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

## make up some random data
np.random.seed(42)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2012-01-01',end='2019-01-01',freq='1M')
passengers = 40 + 10*np.sin(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, len(dates))) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"passenger": passengers}, index=pd.PeriodIndex(data=dates, freq='M'))

def hybridModel(p,q,model):
    out_sample_date = FH(np.arange(12), is_relative=True)
    in_sample_date = FH(df.index, is_relative=False)
    
    max_initial_window = len(df)-max(out_sample_date) ## <-- max initial window cannot be any larger! 
    var_fc = StatsForecastGARCH(p=p,q=q)  
    sqr = SquaringResiduals(forecaster=model, residual_forecaster=var_fc, initial_window=max_initial_window)
    sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=in_sample_date)
    
    y_pred = sqr.predict(in_sample_date) #in sample prediction
    sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=out_sample_date) 
    y_pred2 = sqr.predict(out_sample_date) #out sample prediction 

    fig,ax=plot_series(df, y_pred, y_pred2, labels=["passenger", "y_pred", "y_pred2"])
    plt.plot()
    return sqr,fig,y_pred

forecaster = TBATS(  
    use_box_cox=True,
    use_trend=True,
    use_damped_trend=True,
    sp=12,
    use_arma_errors=True,
    n_jobs=1)
forecaster.fit(df)  

sqr,fig1,y_pred1= hybridModel(1,1,forecaster)
fig1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is working well. Now I am curious why this model does not work like other models such as the simple TBATS model, SquaringResiduals we have to refit the model for in-sample and out-sample prediction while another model simply gives in-sample / out-sample prediction together on single fit.

Comment: @jugesh i'm not totally sure why this is the case. i have a feeling it may have to do with the `initial_window` parameter in SquaringResiduals that isn't used in TBATS, and that when you initially fit the model, you have to choose between either fitting the model to in-sample predictions or out-sample predictions (initially trying to fit the model to FH which includes both in-sample and out-sample will throw an AssertionError related to the cutoff)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify the initial window size parameter in the SquaringResiduals call like this:

```
your_out_of_date_df_index = np.arange(12)
sqr = SquaringResiduals(forecaster=model,  
                        residual_forecaster=var_fc,
                        initial_window=int(len(df))-len(your_out_of_date_df_index))
```

and using your out sample date in the fit function like you tried before:

```
sqr = sqr.fit(df, fh=out_sample_date)  
y_pred2 = sqr.predict(out_sample_date) #out sample prediction
```

Would have posted this as comment, but have too low reputation.

Comment: ValueError: A different forecasting horizon `fh` has been provided from the one seen already in `fit`, in this instance of SquaringResiduals.
I have also tried this.
But you can't predict the in_sample value.